# How to run eslint with mocha with watch option?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, eslint

I would like to do the same with [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/) that I can with [Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/index.html)+[Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/): [Eslint](http://eslint.org/) the code before running the tests, and do this in watch mode (watching the files for changes), so the eslint+tests would rerun on every save.

Watching with Karma works like this: Karma has the [autoWatch](http://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html) option, that watches files for changes. Eslint comes into picture because the client code that is tested with Karma is first processed with webpack which runs eslint on it (with [eslint-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-loader)).

Mocha has [--watch](https://mochajs.org/#usage) option, so I can do `mocha test --watch` to rerun test on file changes.

Eslint has [eslint-watch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-watch), so I can do `esw test --watch` to rerun eslint on file changes.

There is [mocha-eslint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-eslint) (needs configuration) and [eslint-mocha](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-mocha) (no configuration needed), both include eslint in testing, but without having the watch option they are as good as running `eslint test && mocha test`.

Did something miss my attention? Is there already an existing solution out there? Or is there a way around this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So, the answer was that there is a way around, because the solution was not tool specific. The solution was that these watch commands can be run side-by-side. I was too fixated on running eslint before mocha, so this did not came to mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it with [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently).

```
concurrently "mocha test --watch" "esw test --watch"
```